# TypeError: Failed to fetch trying to perform an POST request on API hosted on heroku

Tags: reactjs, post, fetch-api

I'm new to react.js and I'm trying to perform an POST request to an API hosted on Heroku.

```
  fetch('https://my-project.herokuapp.com/addUser', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      parameters: 'yourValue',
    })
   }).then((res) => {
    alert("It Work !")
   }).catch((err) => {
    alert(err)   
   })
```

I'm getting an

> TypeError: Failed to fetch.

Given I didn't find any documentation on React.js I took the one on React Native assuming that the principle remain the same.

Any idea about what happen ?

***EDIT***: After checking the network panel in my browser, it seem that the browser actually send a GET request with a status code 200 instead of POST request. Given I receive an

```
Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

And above all I add the following code in my API (node.js)

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

Thanks

Comment: Is `https://my-project.herokuapp.com/addUser` CORS-enabled? Does it send back the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header? Does the browser actually send the POST request? You can open the Network pane in your browser devtools and reload and examine the requests and responses there. There you should see that the browser has sent an OPTIONS request, and the server has sent a response to that. For the response, what’s the status code shown there? Does the browser send the POST request after that? If so, what’s the status code shown for the response from the server to that POST?

Comment: Please consider using https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45899931/edit to edit/update your question and paste in the details you get from the Network pane in your browser devtools.

Comment: Hello @sideshowbarker I edit my original post. However, can you by the way explain me why should I see an OPTIONS request ? (instead of POST request) thx

Comment: About why the browser sends the OPTIONS request, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, all modern browsers are enforcing [preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) if you want to send [certain headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) in the request(e.g. `Content-Type`). So, for each method in your API you should have a respective `OPTIONS` method to authorize the request if you are using such headers.

Your problem should be solved by adding the `OPTIONS` methods to your API and by adding the [appropriate headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#the_http_response_headers) in the response of your API methods.